# mongodb getting on simple $push The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this simple update api invocation :
this is my document :

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("577a5b9a89xxx32a1"),
        "oid" : {
                "a" : 0,
                "b" : 0,
                "c" : NumberLong("1260351143035")
        },
        "sessions" : [
                {

                }
        ]
}
```

Then i try to insert 1 element into sessions array :

```
db.getCollection('CustomerInfo').update({"oid.c":1260351143035},{$push:{"sessions.$.asessionID":"test123"}})
```

but im getting this error:

```
WriteResult({
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nUpserted" : 0,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 16837,
                "errmsg" : "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: sessions.$.asessionID"
        }
})
```

using $set im getting the same error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error implies,

> "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.
>   Unexpanded update: sessions.$.asessionID",

the positional operator will work if [the array to be updated is also part of the query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/). In your case, the query only involves the embedded document `oid`. The best update operator to use in your case is the **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)** instead.

You can include the sessions array in the query, for example:

```
db.getCollection('CustomerInfo').update(
    { 
        "oid.c": 1260351143035,
        "sessions.0": {} // query where sessions array first element is an empty document
        /* "sessions.0": { "$exists": true } // query where sessions array first element exists */
    },
    {
        "$set": { "sessions.$.asessionID": "test123" }
    }
)
```

Comment: and if it already have element in the array and i want to add another one ?

Comment: Then it's a different scenario where you would need to use `$push`. The above works where your initial `sessions` array has an empty element and this becomes part of the query document for the positional operator to work. However, for the latter case where you want to add another element to the array, you don't need the positional operator because you are pushing a new document to the array using the `$push` operator. Using `$set` together with the positional operator will work when you want to update an existing element and the existing element is part of the query document.

Comment: to create the first element in the array it is working , but now i try to push another element into the array using "oid.c": 1260351143035,
"$push": { "sessions.$.asessionID": "test_2_444" }
and im getting again the error.

im not using "sessions.0": {}

Comment: The error implicitly requires you to include in your query document reference to the array element being updated. For example, you want to push another another element to the array (you don't want to update an existing element), you don't need the positional operator just run the update as `db.CustomerInfo.update({ "oid.c": 1260351143035 }, { "$push": { "sessions": { "asessionID": "test_2_444" } } })`

Comment: If you want to update an existing array element then you need the positional operator with the `$set` and make sure you include the array reference you want to update in the query, for example if you want to change the value of `asessionID` from "test123" to "test_2_444", run the operation `db.CustomerInfo.update({ "oid.c": 1260351143035, "sessions.asessionID": "test123" }, { "$set": { "sessions.$.asessionID": "test_2_444" } })`

Comment: ok great the "sessions": { ...} is working , but now if i want to do 
that is the element doesn't exists create it if does exists update it ?

Comment: Please read the documentaion [**here**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#behavior) and [**there**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-fields-in-embedded-documents).

Comment: i do believe me i do , the sad fact is that i need to translate this to C Driver
and there is almost zero info
i believe you are talking about MONGOC_UPDATE_UPSERT

Comment: Thanks so much for the "the array to be updated is also part of the query". It finally worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) says, you can do as the follow:

```
db.getCollection('CustomerInfo').update(
    { "oid.c": 1260351143035 },
    { $push: {
          "sessions": {
              "asessionID":"test123"
          }
      }
    }
)
```